# Running AppEngine from Command Line

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How can I run AppEngine from command line. Say I want to run it on `http://localhost:8889` and that I want to run `C:/workspace/myapp/src/main/webapp` to be the app deployed on it.

I mean I want to run it stand-alone not using the Eclipse Google plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To run locally on Windows:

```
appengine-java-sdk\bin\dev_appserver.cmd --port=8889 C:\workspace\myapp\war
```

This assumes that `myapp` contains a `war` directory. If that's not the case, modify the path to wherever your `war` directory is for the project you want to run.